# Trying to turn an array of entries into an object but doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to turn an array in which every element is an array containing the key, and the value(like entries), I'm trying to convert it back to an object element by the help of the method `Object.fromEntries(array)` but there seem to be a problem.

This is the error I get: `TypeError: Object.fromEntries requires the first iterable parameter yields objects`

Here's how I use the method:

```
const saved = JSON.parse(Object.fromEntries(localStorage.getItem(key)))
```

The local storage value it should retrieve:

```
[["$$typeof",null],["type",null],["key",null],["ref",null],["props",{"data":"a data containing collections of objects(fetched from an API)"}]
```

Since it might be helpful, what I'm trying to do is to store a react component(yes, I work on ReactJS) to local storage and get it back when necessary.

If you don't think that this portion of code is not the reason why this issue appears, please do let me know.

Comment: You need to parse first, since localStorage stores strings only. `const saved = Object.fromEntries(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)))` However why did you turn this into an array in the first place? You can do `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(theObject))` and just parse that back when you load the data.

Comment: You got it reverse, `const saved = Object.fromEntries(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)))`

Comment: To clarify: JSON.stringify is used to turn an Object into text. This is called serialization and used to transmit the object, or store it. To get back the actual object, you call JSON.parse() on the string you received / loaded.

Comment: Well, I call JSON.stringify when storing it so parsing won't cause any sort of problem I guess

Comment: Tried reversing the Object.fromEntries & JSON.parse but not it says null is not an object

Comment: Again: if you store the stringified object you don't need Object.fromEntries in the first place. And yes, you correctly stringify when storing but your initial code tries to `JSON.parse()` an *object* which makes no sense. https://jsfiddle.net/36xgs5c1/

Comment: Tried it, this is the error I get: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

Comment: I'm trying to store a react component

Comment: Storing React components in *any* state is considered anti-pattern, because it typically leads to stale enclosures of state and props. Instead you should store the data that represents *what* would be rendered and just reinstantiate the React components from the stored state when the UI is rendered.

Comment: Well, by the way, I solved the problem. Instead of storing the component, I stored the data that'd affect which scene will be displayed. It is much easier that way.

Comment: I'll post it soon, just busy right now